# How can a hammer of very less weight apply a large force when hit from a height?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, collision

Consider a hammer of weight 20N . When it is at on the table the only force it can apply on the table is it's weight. so it applies 20N when kept on the table .

But when it is raised and dropped, the force gets multiplied by powers of 10. Even in this case the only force just before collision it can apply is it's weight.

From where the extra huge amount of force appears?

Comment: $F=dp/dt$, so it can be "very more".

Answer (score 0):

> Even in this case the only force just before collision it can apply is it's weight.

No.

The falling hammer is moving. The table surface tries to change this. A change in speed is an acceleration, and accelerations require forces.

Since the time for the change in speed when hitting the table is short, the fraction $$\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$ becomes large. This is a good approximation for the acceleration $a$ that in turn is proportional to the force acting on the table.